# How to consume PubNub chat messages in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, pubnub

I'm new to Flutter and want to incorporate a chat functionality in a Flutter mobile application using PubNub. I was able to send messages to PubNub, but I'm struggling to consume the messages sent by other users. I found an example here: [Flutter Demo App](https://github.com/pubnub/flutter-demo-app), but I'm just looking for the way to consume the messages coming in the stream. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think this is best handled by our support team. Please send the following to support@pubnub.com: your PubNub sub-key, zip your app and attach, reproduce the error with [SDK logging enabled](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/sdks/dart/troubleshooting) and any errors you might be seeing. Support is free, fast and insightful. Include the link to this post so we can answer back when we resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

[Providers](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) may help you with this!  Have a provider for chat messages and update the message list when messages are received in PubNub `subscribe` (& notify listeners). In this way, you can directly consume received messages in the PubNub's `message` callback.
This is one way doing it!